# Video getting darker after Chromakey overlay with FFMPEG

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, video-processing

I'm trying to use FFMPEG to programatically put an overlay with greenscreen, and I'm using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i bg.mp4 -i gs.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:v]chromakey=0x1aa700:0.18:0.01 [ckout];[0:v][ckout]overlay[out]" -preset ultrafast -map "[out]" output.mp4
```

My problem is that, in background videos bigger than the video with chromakey when the video with chromakey ends, the output video gets darker on black (depending on blend values), as seen in this [video](https://youtu.be/T0BBwotnq2w).

The idea is to use this command with Python, so, if you know another way to remove chromakey and overlay vídeos with Python, I would like to know!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `eof_action` option to [overlay filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay):

```
ffmpeg -i bg.mp4 -i gs.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:v]chromakey=0x1aa700:0.18:0.01 [ckout];[0:v][ckout]overlay=eof_action=pass[out]" -preset ultrafast -map "[out]" output.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer, it resulted almost perfectly!  But there is still a black frame at the end of the shortest vídeo (normal video with overlay -> black frame -> normal vídeo)

Comment: Both videos are not made by me since this is only one test, so I don't know if I can share the files, but I think I can share the links of the videos on Youtube so you can download and test them. There they are [background](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WLKJnHu0GC4&ab_channel=NaciriIbrahim) and [overlay](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oFuf9YLV3W0&list=PLYV_dLQijp-hBxNciVJQ3hp_vxWgl1GsG&index=4&ab_channel=SamantaAquino), I made download via this [site](https://youtube4kdownloader.com/). Does this help? Thank you again!

Comment: @JoãoRaimundo `bg.mp4` has 3 black frames in the end. It's part of the video. Not an issue with ffmpeg. You can tell ffmpeg to limit the duration of `bg.mp4` to avoid it: `ffmpeg -i bg.mp4 -t 9 -i gs.mp4 ...`

Comment: Thank you again and sorry for bother you!